# Check Cron Scripts

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

Hello I have an issue with Magento 2.0.2. When I tried to install extensions, it is stuck on Readiness Check and one thing more it is also giving me one or more indexer is invalid please make sure cron job is running properly. See the screen 2. I did not find any tutorial on youtube. I tried to set cron job but it was not working.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you mention in the question how you tried to set cron job, which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2, you need to set a total of 3 cron jobs.

```
*/1 * * * * <path-to-binary> -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run [>> <log-file>&]
*/1 * * * * <path-to-binary> -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/update/cron.php [>> <log-file>&]
*/1 * * * * <path-to-binary> -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run [>> <log-file>&]
```

For more details on how to find `path-to-binary`, `ini-file-path` etc, read [Configure and Run Cron](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)